# private sub worksheet_change(byval target as range) changes in TWO columns

Tags: excel, vba

i want to adjust the following code but I have no clue how to do that...I searched through some threads here ("Combine two Private Sub Worksheet) but I didn't get a solution that worked so far.

So I am kindly asking for your help since my VBA skills are...limited.

```
enter code here
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Const Spalte As Integer = 17     
   Dim C As Range

   If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(Spalte)) Is Nothing Then
   Set Target = Intersect(Target, Columns(Spalte))           
   For Each C In Target                                          
     C.Offset(0, 1).Value = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy") & " um" & 
     Format(Now(), " hh:mm:ss") & " durch " & 
     ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties(7)  

   Next
  End If

  Set C = Nothing
  End Sub
```

All I wanna do now is adjust it, so it also checks whether column 16 was changed or not. If either column 16 OR 17 was changed it should write the date and so on in column 18.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim r As Range
Dim C As Range

Set r = Range("P:Q") 
If Not Intersect(Target, r) Is Nothing Then
    For Each C In Intersect(Target, r)
        Cells(C.Row, 18).Value = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy") & " um" & _
            Format(Now(), " hh:mm:ss") & " durch " & ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties(7)
    Next
End If

Set C = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn’t your commented out bit only grab column A?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 - quite right, I still manage to get my rows and columns mixed up now and then...

Comment: Hahaha it happens!